# Play Market странно ищет

Tags: android, seo, google-play

Найдите карту Грузии MyMap.Ge в Google Play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mymap.ge.mymap

Comment: согласен, странное поведение. Но, неужели пользователи будут вас искать по package-name-y а не по названию и тегам?

Comment: Мне надо, что бы искали именно по этому слову mymap.ge это название проекта, это домен.

Comment: И тегов в маркете нет, негде их прописывать отдельно. Только три поля которые выше перечислил.

Comment: Ну это и есть, грубо говоря, тэги. Попробуйте mymap.ge в описание тоже вставить. Оно у вас нигде не встречается, ни в названии, ни в описании. Вот и не ищется.

Answer (score 5):

Позиция в google play store зависит от многих показателей и учитывает большое кол-во фильтров. Я думаю что даже внутри компании, в этом отделе, это информация доступна не каждому и это хорошо. Что касается именно вашего вопроса, поведение очевидно. Даже если вы указываете точное название приложения, есть аналогии которые имеют похожее словосочетание к примеру *mymaprun*, но они уже имеют большой рейтинг по др позициям(скачивания, отзывы, просмотры, лайки и тд), как выставлены приоритеты мы тоже не знаем. А вот если к примеру ввести так, *mymapE.ge* или любой другой символ, то ваше приложение будет первое потому, что фильтр отфильтрует те приложения 11 штук, так как слово по сути будет не *mymap* а *mymape* и самое подходящее будет ваше приложение. В регулярках "." это любой символ, возможно что фильтр это учитывает? возможно.

Добавлю: 1.Очень сильно влияет на поиск **Название**.
2.Частично влияет на поиск **Краткое описание**. 3.Слабо или вовсе не влияет **Полное описание**.
Это и будут ваши теги для Вашего приложения по приоритетам 1-2-3